# How to add colum with INT data type to an already created table using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Regarding the question, I was able to create the table using the following command:

```
mysql> alter table contact_list ADD contact_ID int;
```

Based on the command above, is there a way to add incremental number values when creating added column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new column *doesn't* need to be a primary key, as some people think. It just needs to be `AUTO_INCREMENT`, which only requires that it be the first column in *any* index (but not strictly the primary key index).

Here's a demo:

```
create table foo (id int primary key);
insert into foo values (123), (456), (789);

alter table foo add column x int auto_increment, add key (x);

select * from foo;
+-----+---+
| id  | x |
+-----+---+
| 123 | 1 |
| 456 | 2 |
| 789 | 3 |
+-----+---+
```

If you already have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column in this table, you can't define a second one in the same table.

```
create table foo (id int auto_increment primary key);
insert into foo values (123), (456), (789);

alter table foo add column x int auto_increment, add key (x);
ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto 
column and it must be defined as a key
```

So you can't automatically populate the new column as you create it. You have to assign the incrementing values manually with an `UPDATE` statement.

```
alter table foo add column x int;

select * from foo;
+-----+------+
| id  | x    |
+-----+------+
| 123 | NULL |
| 456 | NULL |
| 789 | NULL |
+-----+------+

update (select @x:=0) t, foo set foo.x = (@x:=@x+1);

select * from foo;
+-----+------+
| id  | x    |
+-----+------+
| 123 |    1 |
| 456 |    2 |
| 789 |    3 |
+-----+------+
```

Comment: thanks for the answer along with needed educational background

Answer (score 1):

You can do it only if your table does not have a primary key, and you are willing to make the `contact_id` a new primary key:

```
alter table test add contact_id int not null auto_increment primary key;
```

Demo:

```
create table test (name varchar(10));

insert into test(name) values ('quick');
insert into test(name) values ('brown');
insert into test(name) values ('fox');
insert into test(name) values ('jumps');
insert into test(name) values ('over');
insert into test(name) values ('the');
insert into test(name) values ('lazy');
insert into test(name) values ('dog');

alter table test add contact_id int not null auto_increment primary key;

select contact_id, name from test

id name
__ ______
 1 quick
 2 brown
 3 fox
 4 jumps
 5 over
 6 the
 7 lazy
 8 dog
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f323f/1)